# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, backend

I'm trying to set up some routes on the backend of an app I'm building and I keep getting the aforementioned error.

I've made many backends with NodeJS and Express and never ran into this issue. The server seems to start fine and does not give me any errors, but when I try to make an Axios request to it, it does not give me any response. There is absolute no errors apart from the ERR_CONNECTION_LOST one. The server does not give me any indication of what is happening and neither does the front end.

Here is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const secrets = require('./secrets');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3002;
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser);

// ROUTES //
const authRoutes = require('./routes/Auth');
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
res.send('works');
})

// DB CONNECTION //
mongoose.connect(secrets, (err) => {
if (err) {
    console.log(err)
} else {
    console.log("Conncted to DB.")
}
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log("Server running on port: " + PORT);
});
```

Here is my package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon -L server.js"
  },
```

Also, when I try to connect to it with the browser, it loads indefinitely. I'm guessing the server isn't actually running on the desired port?

Comment: where is the code that call the server? or if you use something like postman, how do you use it?
There are not enough details but my guess is that the DB connection is the problem. First, try to put it before all the routes definitions.
Second, check all credentials and configurations of your DB are OK.

Comment: Try to change node version. I ran into similar error message and changing node version helped. Regardless, your question didn't provide enough details

Answer (score 0):

I ended up copy-pasting a snippet from an older project that was using the same DB (sort of scuffed, I know), and it ended up working. My guess is that there was some typo somewhere? I really don't know to be honest. I'll leave a link for the code I copied in case anyone is interested.

https://github.com/caio-ishikawa/simple-notes/blob/master/backend/server.js